# Decompress gz compressed string using Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, gzip, zlib, compression

I want to decompress the following gz compressed string using python3.6:

```
H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQBWsRdKCwAAAA==
```

The decompressed string is "*Hello World*"

I was able to decompress it using online tool - http://www.txtwizard.net/compression but I couldn't find a proper way to do it in python.

I tried zlib and gzip, but they require **bytes** not **str**. I also tried converting it using *io.Bytes()* but of no use. My Code is:

```
import gzip
import io 

class SearchEvents:

def decompressPayload():
    payload = "H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQBWsRdKCwAAAA=="
    payload_bytes = io.BytesIO(payload)
    print(gzip.decompress(payload_bytes))

SearchEvents.decompressPayload()
```

I am expecting "*Hello World*" as output. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SearchEvents.py", line 13, in <module>
SearchEvents.decompressPayload()
File "SearchEvents.py", line 10, in decompressPayload
payload_bytes = io.BytesIO(payload)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Looks like you need to decode the base64 first...

Answer (score 6):

> I want to decompress the following gz compressed string using python3.6:
>
> ```
> ...==
> ```

That's not a gzip-compressed string. At least, not until you Base64-decode it first.

```
>>> gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode('H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQBWsRdKCwAAAA=='))
b'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 1):

For stuff that needs `bytes`, give it `bytes`. Add the `b` prefix to make a `bytes` literal, e.g.:

```
gzip.decompress(b"H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQBWsRdKCwAAAA==")
```

This doesn't work, because that's not valid compressed data. It looks like it's base64 encoded though, so by combining it with `binascii`, you get:

```
import binascii
import gzip
gzip.decompress(binascii.a2b_base64(b"H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVwjPL8pJAQBWsRdKCwAAAA=="))
```

Which produces `b'Hello World'`

Comment: Its giving me another error : *OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'H4')*

Comment: @user93726: Yeah, there was a bit more to it, I was checking to be sure. What's now posted should work.